# C - Segmentation Fault on a char assignment

Tags: c, linux, terminal, segmentation-fault, po

Hello everybody I have a problem here. I am writing a  C Code for reading from a txt file and creating an Index Table from the informations inside this txt. I am reading txt file with getchar() function and taking every char one by one in my "ch" variable. When I am running my program, I am taking the segmantation fault error on the terminal. Here is the all code and I commented the code lines where I am thinking the problem in and which is associated with my question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{ // Here is my structure of Index Table
char name[10]; // Here is my char array for storing the name data from file
int key;
} fileIndex;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i, k=0, j=0, lines=0, offset=0;
char ch;

FILE *pFile;

pFile= fopen("/etc/passwd","r");



if (pFile == NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file.\n");
exit(1);
}


while(!feof(pFile))
{

ch = fgetc(pFile);

if(ch == '\n')
{
lines++;
}
}

fileIndex *index = (fileIndex *)malloc(lines);

rewind(pFile);

index[0].key=0;

while(!feof(pFile))
{

ch = fgetc(pFile);
offset++;

if(ch == '\n'){
k++;
index[k].key=offset;}

if(offset==index[k].key+1){// And here I want to take the name information from my txt file
while(ch!=':'){
index[k].name[j]=ch;// Here I am assinging char values one by one to my char array's corresponding index.
j++;
    }
 }

}


}
```

Can you help me to fix it please, I tried everything before putting this here. Thank you..

Comment: You say you've tried everything... did you try to run the program under a debugger? Where does the crash happen?

Comment: `malloc(lines)` --> `malloc(lines * sizeof(*index))`. Also You need to set the null-terminator  to  `name`.

Comment: I don't have a debugger, I am working on linux gedit. I don't know much things about programming actually..

Comment: @Ozan Yurtsever install the eclipse and you will have the debugger

Comment: How can I set the null-terminator to name ? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Also see [Why is "while (!feof(file))" always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @OzanYurtsever like `index[k].name[j]='\0';`

Comment: I am still taking the segmentation fault error.

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/qdJHYu)

Comment: But it gives offsets wrong

Comment: Okey I fixed the problem